# How can I deploy multiple Stateless web API independently, which are under one Service Fabric Application?

Tags: service, webapi, stateless

I have three web API (Stateless Web API) under Services in Service Fabric Application (One Application).
On the cluster explorer, it shows one Application >> Types >> then all three Services. Its deployed and works good but I couldn't deploy the Web APIs independently.

How can I deploy the web API independently? Should I create 3 Application and add 1 Web API each or Should I keep it as it is (One Application and three Web API underneath)?

The Goal is to have the ability to customize the APIs anytime and deploy them independently without affecting others.

I tried 3 Application and 1 Web API each approach but got deployment error on the new applications: error in XML document (7, 4)

Answer (score 0):

When you publish the SF app, you can just upgrade the manifest version of the stateless web api you want to deploy. The deploy will only replace the service in the cluster that has an upgraded manifest version.